# Issue in Converting iPhone application to iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have applied the required settings for converting my iPhone app to run on iPad. So, when i Build and Run, the window is an iPad window but the size is not compatible, meaning that no proper scaling has taken place. 
Moreover, the xib files formed inside the iPad resources still show iPhone window. Please suggest where I am wrong

Comment: You need to explain wat "required settings" have u done....see you need to add xib's for the ipad and conditions inside the code to choose which xib has to be chosen....

Comment: Dude I have added a new target and switched my simulator to iPad simulator 3.2

Comment: Please tell me what else has to be done..

Comment: Create a master application .... it includes both code for iphone and ipad ... or make a universal app

Comment: Setting target only wont work, you need to create all .xib files for iPad (or storyboard in case you are using storyboard) and than you have to check, on which device your app is running and according to that you need to load UI files.

Comment: dude thats what i did, i have completed my iPhone app and chose the universal app option but the problem still continues :(

Comment: @suraj Thanx for clarifying dude. Can you tell me how and where to do the checking part?

Comment: In your info.plist is there two references: Main storyboard file base name for both iPhone and iPad - also check the respective storyboard file attached to that key

Comment: @Zack say your AppDelegate you want to load ViewController as RootView & for ViewController Class you have two Xib file say  ViewController_iPhone.xib & ViewController_iPad.xib,you can do something like following...
'if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }'
This approach you can apply where ever you want to load any view.

Comment: @Zack You need to set from iPhone to universal device and set the constraint to your .xib file.